# Complex scalar fields on real manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a *real* smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $d$. What I want to do is construct scalar fields on $M$ over $\mathbb C$ so that I can do derivatives(parametrized by spacetime, say, a 4 dimensional real manifold).

If $f:M\to\mathbb C$, I guess I could do $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w^i}=\dfrac{\partial w^j}{\partial z^i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w^j}$(given some charts) as basis transformations. The problem is that each basis $z_i$ needs two real numbers to be defined, so the tangent bundle needs to have dimension $3d$(I think). So, for the dimension of the tangent bundle to be double the dimension of the base, either the manifold is complex(with complex coordinates, which I don't want) or the field is real(which I also don't want).

I have read(wiki) that scalar fields can be complex, without much difference on which approach you take, which makes sense because, in QFT, the lagrangian(which is a function $TM\to\mathbb C$) is taken as if it was a real field and there is no distinction between a complex and real field, you just have a spacetime and assign a complex number to every point, that's it.

I have read about *almost complex structures*, which is defined as a particular linear map in the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold(note it does not say anything about the manifold apart from it being smooth). Is this the structure I need? If I have an almost complex structure, what is the dimension of $TM$(given $M$ has real dimension $d$), and, more importantly, what is $TM$? What are its basis? How does basis vectors change, is my intuition of chart transitions correct? Do the dimension of $TM$ remain as double the dimension of $M$?

Either way, It seems I have a lot of questions, but I cannot find any book or reference that explains how complex fields are defined on real manifolds without going to the complex manifolds realm(maybe there aren't, for my surprise!). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I Sorry, I didn't say it, but the goal is to generalize to complex vectors, instead of solely scalars, so when I said above derivatives, I really meant partial and covariant derivatives. Based on @Vercassivelaunos' comment, could I just make a vector bundle $\mathbb C\to E\to^\pi M$ which allows to define a connection and then call the "fields" just sections $M\to E$ to do derivatives properly? Would this be the correct way to make complex "fields" out of a real manifold?

Comment: Given a complex scalar field $f$, write $f =g + \sqrt {-1} h$ for some real scalar fields $g, h$. Then let $\nabla_j g+ \sqrt{-1} \nabla_j h$. Is that what you want?

Comment: $M$ is a real manifold, $\mathbb C$ is a real manifold. Functions between the two can be differentiated like functions between arbitrary real manifolds, and the differential will be a linear map $\mathrm df_p:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb C$, where we can naturally identify $T_{f(p)}\mathbb C\cong\mathbb C$. There are no restrictions to the dimensions of the tangent bundles which could put a restriction on the structure of the manifolds.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos So they are not considered a field per se, they are just differentiable functions with no relation to $TM$. Thanks. I like the fact that this does not restrict the structure of $M$.

Comment: I guess, but then $f$ is not the result of applying a one-form to a tangent vector, as they are complex and $T_pM$ is a real vector space.

Comment: All differentiable functions have some relation to the tangent bundle, since the differential of a function $f:M\to N$ is a function $\mathrm df:TM\to TN$. I just took the restriction of $\mathrm df$ to the tangent spaces $T_pM$ and $T_{f(p)}N$.

Comment: Anyway, a good definition of a real field (tensor, vector, scalar) is a smooth section of the tensor bundle $T^r(TM)\otimes T^s(T^\ast M)$ ($r$-times tensor product of $TM$ and $s$-times tensor product of $T^\ast M$). For $r=1, s=0$, this is a vector field, and for $r=s=0$ it's a scalar field. In that case, the bundle is also just $M\times \mathbb R$, and a section is just a map $M\to\mathbb R$. Replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$ and you should get a sensible definition of a complex scalar field.